# problem with gradle project refresh in android studio 3.0

Tags: android

I installed android studio 3.0 on ubuntu 16.04. But when I open a project with it, I get the error below:

> Gradle 'MyApplication' project refresh failed.
>
> ```
> Error:Operation not permitted(Socket creation failed)
> ```

How can I fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the permissions. I opened android studio using sudo and it worked!

Comment: I don't think it should be necessary to run Android Studio as root, which is what you're doing when you run it with `sudo`. If you edit your question with details about how you installed Android Studio, and also say if *all* projects produce that error or just some, that might help you get answers with other solutions you might like better.

Comment: I downloaded it from developer.android.com and then ran it from terminal. I've done the same thing for android studio 2 and there was no problem. And it happens for all the projects. I think its not a problem with android studio. Apparently my account doesn't have the permission to create sockets. I think if I get the permission, it will be ok.